# turned in a rather unimpressive interview performance -- what does "turned in" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> For a while, Taligent enjoyed a cachet in the industry as the place where Apple and IBM sent many of their best and brightest. If you managed to get a job at Taligent, you had "made it."
>   I almost didn't make it. I had wanted to work at Taligent for some time and eventually got the chance, but **turned in** a rather unimpressive interview performance (coworkers kidded me about that for years afterward) and wasn't offered the job.

What does that phrasal verb mean in this context?

Comment: The phrasal verb "turn in" means to give or produce.

Comment: It can also mean "submit" - please use a dictionary and edit the question if you still do not understand the meaning. [Here are some to get you started](http://onelook.com/?w=turn+in&ls=a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Merriam-Webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turn%20in) defines *turn in* in this context as:

> to acquit oneself of :  put on, produce.
>
> > *Turned in* a good performance

I assume it's self-explanatory now.